# How do I pass a variable as prop for setState in React?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, state, react-props

I am trying to build a modular dropdown list component in react. It also acts as a filter for a search app.
I created an object for all the types of dropdowns and their respective options as shown in the code below. 
I then mapped the object and was able to make the component I wanted to. 

The problem now is, I have to update changes made to the state of filters. But I cant pass the variable "val". It takes val literally and adds a new object member. 
How do I fix it?

```
import React from "react";

export const FilterOptions = (props) => {
  const types = {
    gender: ["", "Male", "Female", "Genderless", "Unknown"],
    status: ["", "Dead", "Alive", "Unknown"],
    species: ["", "Human", "Alien"],
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row">
      {Object.keys(types).map((val, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="mx-4">
            {val}
            <select
              name={val}
              key={index}
              onChange={(event) =>
                props.setFilters({ ...props.filters, val(This variable here is the problem): event.target.value })
              }
            >
              {types[val].map((type, index) => {
                return (
                  <option key={index} value={type}>
                    {type}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the square brackets:

```
props.setFilters({ ...props.filters, [val]: event.target.value })
```